# My enqueue admin style function doesn't work because of ?=ver

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development

I'm using the following to enqueu an admin style:

```
wp_enqueue_style('pk-admin-css', PULUGIN_URL . 'css/admin.css');
```

This outputs the style file appended with the ?=ver parameter which results in the file loading with no content.

I can fix this by removing that parameter like so:

```
wp_enqueue_style('pk-admin-css', PULUGIN_URL . 'css/admin.css', array(), null)
```

basically give it the version a nul value which removes it. My question though is.. The front-end style loads fine with that version number but why my admin style is not? Can someone explain this for me?

Thank you.

Comment: This is strange. Could you please provide a screenshot of your browser's console?

Answer (score 0):

```
// load css into the admin page use admin_enqueue_scripts or admin_print_styles

function mytheme_enqueue_options_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'mytheme-options-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/admin.css' ); 
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_enqueue_options_style' );
```

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with version. First of all you have a typo in constant name: `PULUGIN_URL`. Even if you change it to `PLUGIN_URL`, it will not work, because such constant does not exists. When you do it from within plugin, use proper function. In your case it should be: `plugin_dir_url(__FILE__)`. Your code should be:

```
function wpse_enqueue_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style('pk-admin-css', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'css/admin.css');
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_enqueue_style' );
```